# Play Controller from the bottom up

Tags: playframework

There are a lot of tutorials showing all the powerful features of Play, but I'm having trouble getting a solid understanding of the basics.

To start with: How can I make a Controller which, when given URL /hi/there?name=fred, displays "Hello, fred" in an HTML Layout?

Also: Are the template helpers documented anywhere? Are they used as much as they are in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give an url to a controller. You link a controller function to an url by setting the routes file.

conf/routes:

```
GET     /index  controllers.Application.index()
```

The "/index" url will return the result of the function controllers.Application.index().

There is the list of all the helpers :
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper
Look at the comments, there is all the documentation you need.